# Using Timer only once

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I want to use a timer only once, at 1 second after the initialization of my main form.
I thought the following would have a message box saying "Hello World" just once, but actually a new message box says "Hello World" every one second.

Why so? I had put `t.Stop()` in the tick event.
Also, do I need to dispose the timer somehow to avoid memory leakage?

```
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.Interval = 1000;                
        t.Tick += delegate(System.Object o, System.EventArgs e)
                        { MessageBox.Show("Hello World"); t.Stop(); };

        t.Start();
```

Please help and show if there is a better way of doing this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace `MessageBox.Show("Hello World"); t.Stop();` with `t.Stop();MessageBox.Show("Hello World");`. Because you're not pressing OK in time, the timer has already ticked again and you never reached the stop code.

Comment: Ok, that works. Thanks.
But what's the logic?
Why the order matters?

Comment: @zaidwaqi: The thread goes into MessageBox.Show method, and doesn't leave until you press OK. But you don't press OK fast enough, and it has already opened a new MessageBox.

Comment: Oh :)
What about disposing the timer? Is it needed since the timer will not be used anymore?

Comment: @zaidwaqi, well you could call t.Dispose() after t.Stop()

Comment: @SebastianGodelet As long as he doesn't need it again, he should probably be doing that anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Put `t.Stop();` before the `MessageBox.Show("Hellow World");`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this also with System.Timers.Timer and setting AutoReset to false. I was looking into which timer to use and prefer this one as it does not require the separate stop command.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;

System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer() {
    Interval = 1000,
    AutoReset = false
};

t.Elapsed  += delegate(System.Object o, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    { Console.WriteLine("Hell");}; 
t.Start();
```