# How to set Connection.Closed Event to make it reconnect in SignalR?

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr.client

I want to set a Timer on the `disconnected` event to automatically attempt reconnection.

```
var querystringData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
querystringData.Add("uid", Uid);
var connection = new HubConnection(HubUri, querystringData);
_hub = connection.CreateHubProxy(HubName);
connection.Start(new LongPollingTransport()).Wait();
connection.Closed += ???; //how to set this event to try to reconnect?
```

I only know how to set it in Javascript with the `disconnected` callback:

```
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       $.connection.hub.start();
   }, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
});
```

But how to do the same using the connection's `Closed` event in C# (WinForms)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take it as *pseudo* code, I cannot really test it and it might not compile, but it should give you an idea about the direction to take and you should be able to fix potential defects:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

//...your stuff about query string...
_hub = connection.CreateHubProxy(HubName);

//quick helper to avoid repeating the connection starting code
var connect = new Action(() => 
{
    connection.Start(new LongPollingTransport()).Wait();
});

Timer t = new Timer();
t.Interval = 5000;
t.Tick += (s, e) =>
{
    t.Stop();
    connect();
}

connection.Closed += (s, e) => 
{
    t.Start(); 
}

connect();
```

This is actually more a timer-related question than a SignalR question, on that regard you can find [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535722/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-a-timer) [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841177/using-timer-only-once) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186084/how-do-you-add-a-timer-to-a-c-sharp-console-application) about `Timer`s (there are more then one type) that should help you with understanding this code, adjusting details and fighting with nuances like threading issues etc.